# Mysql:Need to upload data to database, get duplicate key error - how can dup keys be ignored

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-5.1

I'm uploading data to a db (mysql 5.1.42) from a dump file using mysql command line and get duplicate key error.

This is the format I use:

> /mnt/temp# mysql -u username -p -h url_of_db_master -D farm2  <
>   db_dump_part_file_a

Hoe can I tell mysql to ignore duplicate keys?

Thanks !

Comment: can you post full query like this, to avoid duplicates since i import large db size around 500mb In this, `mysql -u username -p database_name < "/path/file.sql"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to decide what you want to happen when a duplicate is found, because you can:

- [ignore it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) (`insert ignore ...`)
- [do something](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (`insert ... on duplicate key update`)

Since `mysqldump` usually dumps each table in a single `insert` statement, you can easily just add those keywords in the dump file.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update) for a more in-depth discussion on the pros and cons of the two possiblities.

Comment: Thanks Matt,
This is a large dump and I cant replace the inserts. I was hopeing there is some option that I can give the mysql command prompt that tells it to ignore the errors. Most of the data is statistic so losing a few rows is OK.

Comment: @Nir what do you mean by large -- lots of rows or lots of tables?  You'll have to make **one** change for each table, regardless of number of rows.  If you're only dumping one table, then you have to make one change.